# FrontPage migration to SharePoint 2010 or WSS3.0

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, migration

Can any one suggest best practice for migrating Microsoft FrontPage pages to SharePoint 2010 or WSS3.0?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, you have to rebuild FrontPage web sites as SharePoint application pages.

On an interesting side note, in sps 2013 you can use the Design Manager tool that's able to convert any HTML pages to SharePoint pages for you.

Other possibility is check with the 3rd party migration tools may be they have option for this.